# Facebook api for the list of users who check in my facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

How can I get list of users who check in my page(location). Check in counts can get by graph api but didn't get the users details.

Comment: There is no API for that.

Comment: do you have any other solutions?